# Cocoa Mac blue select highlight color

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolor

I'm not able to find a color used by the system to highlight a NSSegmentedControl inside a popover.

[image]

I've tried a lot of the standard NSColors with no luck, as well as try to get it from the NSSegmentedControl itself using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [segments.cell highlightColorWithFrame:segments.bounds inView:segments]);
```

That reports it as being `secondarySelectedControlColor` which is really not it.

I also noticed the same color being used to highlight buttons in Xcode 5:
[image]

Just to clarify: this is in OS X 10.8.

Comment: It may be a custom color, have you tried measuring the color value using DigitalColorMeter? It also seems more of a gradient than just a color so you're gonna have to measure the top and bottom color value of it.

Comment: Measuring it only gives the color values under the cursor. As it's a gradient and/or a drop shadow the color values don't help at all as it's impossible or really really hard to replicate the exact effect.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the information?  If it's a gradient, it may be reporting the correct "color", but the color itself may be a tint over the gradient and therefore not be something you can render directly without re-creating the gradient and applying the tint.

Comment: I'm trying to style a NSTableView to have text in that color/gradient while selected.